# Why JTextArea is small?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jtextarea

I try to make a simple app in SWING: using BorderLayout layout on the JFrame, i put on SOUTH an executing button, on WEST a panel that contains a combobox and on EAST a panel that contains 2 JTextAreas. The problem is, both JTextArea are damn small. Any help and explanation will be welcomed.

**This is the code for the panel with the 2 text areas**

```
package cipher;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

class TextPanel extends JPanel {

    private JTextArea inputArea, outputArea;

    public TextPanel() {

        initSize();
        initTextArea();
        initBorder();
        initLayout();

        packing();

    }

    private void packing() {

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        add(inputArea,gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        add(outputArea,gbc);

    }

    private void initBorder() {

        Border outer = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5);
        Border inner = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Text");
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(outer,inner));

    }

    private void initLayout() {

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    }

    private void initTextArea() {

        inputArea = new JTextArea();
        inputArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(385,400));

        outputArea = new JTextArea();
        outputArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(385,400));

    }

    private void initSize() {

        Dimension size = getPreferredSize();
        size.width = 390;
        setPreferredSize(size);

    }

}
```

I've tried using setSize(x,y) but without success. I've tried using JTextArea(rows,columns) but without success. I've used even setPreferredSize with a Dimension but no succeed.

[image: screenshot of results]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resize JTextArea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21813660/resize-jtextarea)

Comment: Probably because the preferred size is to large for the container, so it's filling back to it's minimum size.  First, don't set the preferred size directly.  Instead make use of the rows/columns properties.  Second, use `GridBagConstraints#fill` to override these properties

Comment: The above comment applies to the panel as well. Don't attempt to set the preferred size of the panel. The preferred size will be calculated based on the components added to the panel. Also, note that you invoke `initSize()` before you even add components to the panel so the preferred size will be (0, 0). Get rid of that method and code.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). (That code needs at least a `main(String[])` method to put it on screen to be an MRE / SSCCE.) **Edit:** But please heed the advice of @MadProgrammer & camickr before turning it into an MRE / SSCCE. I believe they've given enough advice to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probable cause of your issue is the container area is smaller than the preferred size of the text area, `GridBagLayout` will then default to the minimum size instead.

This is a good example of why you should avoid setting these properties directly and instead make use of the layout manager and the components properties.

To start with, make use of the `JTextArea`'s `column` and `rows` properties.  This will make a better "guess" at the amount of space it needs to display text to fit within these confines.

Second, use `GridBagConstraints#fill` to override `GridBagLayout` and force it to make use of the available space

[image: Fill the space]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TextPanel());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TextPanel extends JPanel {

        private JTextArea inputArea, outputArea;

        public TextPanel() {

            initTextArea();
            initBorder();
            initLayout();

            packing();

        }

        private void packing() {

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            add(inputArea, gbc);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            add(outputArea, gbc);

        }

        private void initBorder() {

            Border outer = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5);
            Border inner = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Text");
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(outer, inner));

        }

        private void initLayout() {

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        }

        private void initTextArea() {

            // The borders are just here so you can see the different text areas
            inputArea = new JTextArea(10, 20);
            inputArea.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            outputArea = new JTextArea(10, 20);
            outputArea.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));

        }

    }
}
```

I'd also change...

```
inputArea = new JTextArea(10, 20);
inputArea.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
outputArea = new JTextArea(10, 20);
outputArea.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
```

and make use of `JScrollPane`s instead of `LineBorder`

Comment: My gosh, solved it! It's so nice to learn something new. I've had no idea about these informations so far. Cheers!